# Definir um array como circular no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como conseguiria dar um *loop* na *array*? O código pega o dia atual e soma um valor `x`. Por exemplo, eu gostaria que quando chegasse segunda-feira aonde o script

```
document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 6] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 6] +  " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
```

(ele vai somar segunda-feira mais 6 dias), porém dá erro, pois só restará mais 5 dias na *array*. Então o que eu queria é que ele criasse um *loop*.

```
var now = new Date();
var dias = ["DOMINGO","SEGUNDA","TERÇA","QUARTA","QUINTA","SEXTA","SABADO"];
var meses = ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT","NOV", "DEZ"];
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay()] + ", " + now.getDate () + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 1] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 1] + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 2] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 2] + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 3] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 3] + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 4] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 4] + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 5] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 5] + " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
document.getElementById("g").innerHTML = (dias[now.getDay() + 6] + ", " + [now.getDate () + 6] +  " de " + meses [now.getMonth() ]);
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quer fazer, mas já pensou em pegar o resto da divisão por 7? Assim, se o resultado da soma ultrapassar 6, volta ao início da lista.

Comment: Bem isso que eu gostaria de fazer, mas como faria isso?O que eu deveria usar?Como deveria fazer?Se puder me ajudar eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Como eu disse, não está claro o que você quer fazer. Se puder [edit] a pergunta e tentar ser mais claro, talvez seja possível. Explique, por exemplo, o que o código deveria fazer e quem são todos esses elementos no DOM;

Answer (score 3):

Respondendo à questão principal, você não consegue, literalmente, definir um array como circular, mas você consegue o percorrer de maneira circular utilizando **aritmética modular**. Isso é facilmente alcançável em JavaScript utilizando o operador de módulo (`%`) e um pequeno cálculo com ele.

Dado um array `arr` de comprimento `n` e um valor `val` armazenado no array e que será obtido através de um índice `i`, a maneira circular, e mais segura, de acessar o array, *desconsiderando* qualquer que seja o valor e sinal de `i`, seria:

```
let val = arr[(i % n + n) % n];
```

Esse pequeno cálculo é necessário porque o JavaScript sempre avalia a operação de módulo como o **resto** da divisão entre o dividendo (primeiro operando) e divisor (segundo operando) desconsiderando seus sinais, *mas atribuindo ao resto o sinal do dividendo*. Esse comportamento nem sempre resulta no efeito de "loop" desejado da aritmética modular, podendo resultar em um acesso incorreto de uma posição negativa do array.

Por exemplo, dado `i = -5` e `n = 3`, o JavaScript avaliaria a expressão `-5 % 3` em `-2`, o que é incorreto e resultaria num erro de acesso ao array. O correto na aritmética modular seria a expressão ser avaliada em `1`, o que é obtido pelo JavaScript com o cálculo da expressão `(-5 % 3 + 3) % 3`.

Pra finalidade que estavas querendo e mostraste parcialmente em código, você até poderia utilizar a operação de módulo diretamente -- como o Anderson mencionou quando sugeriu "pegar o resto da divisão". A solução proposta aqui é apenas mais genérica e mais segura, pois não é garantido (assertado) pelo teu código que o valor final do índice de acesso ao array será sempre positivo, embora, agora, estejas confiando em funções da biblioteca padrão da linguagem.

Referências e mais informações:

1. https://pt.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic
2. https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic (mesmo conteúdo do link anterior, mas em inglês, com mais comentários do professor e dos alunos)
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation
5. https://dev.to/maurobringolf/a-neat-trick-to-compute-modulo-of-negative-numbers-111e